# php excel read with multiple tabs

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using this code http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader for reading excel files with PHP.

It works great, but problem is when I open multiple tabs file with this code, it makes the page very large.

When I open a single tab file its work fine.

I need the tabs to look like excel as shows.

[image]

check above image. I need tabs like screenshot left image and right image, I open same file but don't have tabs actually that same file but the left original excel image show with tabs and right php script that i am sing not showing tabs..

I need any script which reads excel file the same as excel does and show all same as excel shows current script work fine but its not work with multiple tabs file the extention i am using is .xls

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot of what you're talking about (and some sample code of what isn't working? Use imgur to post your screenshot.

Comment: If you tag the question as PHPExcel, why not actually try using [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com)

Comment: @MarkBaker ofcourse i download many time this but i dont know how its works i tried many time but dont know how to run excel worksheet. when i run this as they in install.txt i just saw multi lines text thats show ex. 3mb read 5mb etc etc. i d0nt undedtsand this please help me

Comment: I don't know what you're reading as the install.txt file, or how you're reading it; but it's a plain text file - https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/install.txt and there's plenty of documentation and examples in the distribution package to explain how to use it

Comment: @MarkBaker ok i try again. and in simple word currently i am using script work fine but when open single excel file wich have multiple tabs as i show in screenshot. its dont show tabs. just problem is i need script which show all data if excel file have multiple tabs then show. maybe u understand ? and this link github u give me is have this which i want ?

Comment: @MarkBaker now i try this but still confuse every file create excel xls or xlsx file. i want to open excel xls file with php :(( not create

Comment: In the /Examples directory, you have 07reader.php that demonstrates how to read an Excel file, and 17html.php that demonstrates writing as HTML. I don't know how much more I can do with the amount of documentation and examples provided with the package besides simply giving you 5 simple lines of code (that can be extracted by reading the docs and examples) to do what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("myExcelFile.xls");
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'HTML');
$objWriter->writeAllSheets();
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

You can play with the styling if you want the sheet list as tabs, and add a bit of js to hide/unhide the individual sheets by modifying PHPExcel/Writer/HTML.php

Comment: Done:- ))
now looking another little problem if feel problem then tease u again bye : -pppp

Comment: some time i get this Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\ex\ex\Classes\PHPExcel.php on line 379 <-= error. why is it ??

Comment: It means that your script takes longer than 30 seconds to run, but that PHP has a limit of 30 seconds execution time

Comment: but why i get this error? some time it work fine. how i solve this ? and what wrong ? and also i posted q question about cell position styling problem in this script cell float right side and not look perfect i mean not look like excel can u help me please???

Comment: You solve it either by increasing your PHP time limit, or by writing your script more efficiently - but I can't guess what your script does... are you simply using the code I posted? Or doing anything else? How big is your spreadsheet? What format is it?

Comment: ofcourse i just use ur posted code not doing any thing. and file format is xls. my spread sheed multiple tabs divide in 8 tabs here screenshort url http://i43.tinypic.com/3476xr4.png look dersiging problblem

Comment: and also i forget to tell you i remove all code in 17html.php and just past ur posted code.

Comment: It looks like you're working with very large spreadsheets; but also with a lot of empty cells that still need parsing by the script... it might be an idea to clean up the spreadsheets before loading them up

Comment: ok i try to remove epty cels did you read my last comment ? as i say i remove all code in 17html.php and just past ur 5 line code. is make any problem ??

Comment: That shouldn't make any problem